# Am I using lists wrong? Memory leak in this simple python / pyglet code

Tags: python, list, memory-leaks, pyglet

I'm writing a simple 'avoid the falling enemies' type game in pyglet. The objects are generated above the screen, travel downward, and are destroyed when they pass below the visible screen. However, I'm doing something terribly wrong and the longer the program runs, the number of objects rises and rises. (It was slowing down and I discovered the problem with objgraph.) When I remove this class, the problem disappears.

Falling Enemy class:

```
class Enemy(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(img=images.enemy_anim["front"], **kwargs)
        self.out_of_bounds = False

    def update(self, dt):
        self._move(dt)
        self._check_boundaries(dt)
        self._check_kill_condition()

    def _move(self, dt):
        self.y -= ENEMY_SPEED * dt

    def _check_boundaries(self, dt):
        if self.y + self.height < 0:
            self.out_of_bounds = True

    def _check_kill_condition(self):
        if self.out_of_bounds:
            enemy_list.remove(self)
            self.delete
```

Main method code:

```
enemy_list = []

def add_enemy(*args, **kwargs):
    randx = random.randint(0,
               WINDOW_WIDTH - images.enemy_anim["front"].get_max_width())
    randy = WINDOW_HEIGHT + images.enemy_anim["front"].get_max_height()
    enemy_list.append(Enemy(x=randx, y=randy, batch=update_batch))

def update(dt):
    for sprite in enemy_list:
        sprite.update(dt)

#send the above functions to the pyglet scheduler
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/TICKS_PER_SECOND)
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(add_enemy, 1/ENEMY_ADD_RATE)
```

I have my enemy animation stored in a separate module (images) in a dictionary (images.enemy_anim).

I create an enemy with the reference inside a list.

When the enemy dies, I tell it to remove itself from the list. I've checked the length of the list during runtime and it's always the appropriate length. So the list isn't growing out of control. The object should have no references after it's removed from the list, right?

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The problem was that I had `self.delete` instead of `self.delete()`. Stupid mistake...

Comment: In `_check_kill_condition` is the last line correct? Shouldn't it be something like `self.delete()`?

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. What a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510937/bakuriu) pointed out in the comment above, the problem was that I simply forgot a pair of parentheses on the pyglet sprite `delete` method. A huge problem cause by a simple and obvious mistake...

Comment: Hi Josh, I would recommend that you actually mark mawimawi's answer as correct. He is the one who deserves the rep as he actually answered the question with detail. I don't know, it's up to you, it just seems fair. Good day!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of deleting an object inside its own method, I'd go a different approach and delete the sprites in an additional schedule_interval like this:

```
def delete_enemy(*args, **kwargs):
    items_to_delete = []
    for enemy in enemy_list:
        if enemy.out_of_bounds:
            items_to_delete.append(enemy)
    for item in items_to_delete:
        enemy_list.remove(item)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(delete_enemy)
```

And of course remove the line `self._check_kill_condition()` in `Enemy.update`.

**Edit:** I don't know pyglet, but if this approach does not work either, then something inside pyglet keeps a reference to your sprite. The sprite could be referenced in a canvas or some similar object. There should be an API call in pyglet to delete a Sprite totally (i.e. from the canvas). This call should then be used right after my `enemy_list.remove(item)` call.

Comment: You're right about there being an API call in pyglet to delete a Sprite totally. It's `sprite.delete()` and I had `sprite.delete`. Thanks for the help!